# Get last css or js code after dynamic load

Tags: javascript, php, css

While I'm developing web page, i use time() function for dynamic refresh.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme.css<?php echo '?'.time(); ?>">
```

but now my code(style sheet) is pretty stable, so I want to use cache data now.
how can I do it? I removed ? and time, but I could see old version only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change query to static value

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/theme.css?v=stable">
```

This will refresh the old cache from the browser (one time only) and will generate new one from the new version

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the browser. If you are using Google Chrome, then you can go Ctrl + Shift + Del (For windows and Linux), Uncheck everything except Cache, change the dropdown to the beginning of time. This will delete your entire cache for all websites, and force css files to be re-downloaded.

I would recommend for the future that rather than using `<?php echo '?'.time(); ?>`, that you install a browser extension such as [Cache Killer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap) if you are using Chrome. You can also [disable cache when developer tools is open](http://nicholasbering.ca/tools/2016/10/09/devtools-disable-caching/).